# MSVC can't compile this code, complains `error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant` without constexpr

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

MSVC can't compile the below code (https://godbolt.org/z/feenYcaen):

> error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant

Line 10 comes from MSVC's own `offsetof`. I think this statement is a constant expression, even if it's not, can't MSVC compute this at runtime? Is this an MSVC bug?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct A{};

template<typename T, A T::*MPtr>
struct KKP {
    private:
   static const std::uintptr_t c =
   ((size_t) & reinterpret_cast<char const volatile&>((((T*)0)->*MPtr)));
};

struct PC {
    A t;
};

size_t f() {
    KKP<PC, &PC::t> ar;
}
```

In fact, I solved this by using a member function instead of a class member (https://godbolt.org/z/c65eEnvd7), but then MSVC becomes more confusing for me:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct A{};

template<typename T, A T::*MPtr>
struct KKP {
    private:
    static constexpr size_t c() {
       return ((::size_t) & reinterpret_cast<char const volatile&>((((T*)0)->*MPtr)));
    }
};

struct PC {
    A t;
};

size_t f() {
    KKP<PC, &PC::t> ar;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `offsetof`? What underlying and actual problem is that supposed to solve? Right now your question is really an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please always ask about the actual and underlying problem directly. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I was just transplanting a c++ project from Linux to windows. this code is a miniset of the transplanting issue I face. And thanks, I'll read these tutorials.

Comment: Note that the library offsetof uses `->m`, not `->*m`. Huge difference! Also note that the standard library is allowed to use non-standard code, while user code is not. This is one reason why `offsetof` is part of the standard library.

Comment: Regarding C2131, I suggest you refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2131?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C2131)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-170). And could you please tell me why the code is confusing you?

Comment: @Yujian Yao - MSFT  because I think `static const` don't require `constant`, now I totally understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> offsetof cannot be implemented in standard C++ and requires compiler
> support - [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof)

From the quote, it immediately follows that both code samples do not conform to the C++ standard.

There are null pointer dereference undefined behavior and `reinterpret_cast` conversion in the expression that is supposed to be `constexpr`.
[Both do not belong to core constant expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr):

> A core constant expression is any expression whose evaluation would
> not evaluate any one of the following:
>  8. an expression whose evaluation leads to any form of core language undefined behavior ...
>  18. reinterpret_cast

The problem still persists in the second code sample because the function is not in fact `constexpr`, and the program is ill-formed.

> A constexpr function must satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - there exists at least one set of argument values such that an invocation of
>   the function could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant
>   expression ... (until C++23)
>
> For constexpr function templates and constexpr member functions of class templates, at least one specialization must satisfy the abovementioned requirements. Other specializations are still considered as constexpr, even though a call to such a function cannot appear in a constant expression. *If no specialization of the template would satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function when considered as a non-template function, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required (until C++23)*.
> [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

Consider [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Gf8j6Mo1s)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct A{};

template<typename T, A T::*MPtr>
class KKP {
public:    // make the function public
    static constexpr size_t c() {
       return ((::size_t) & reinterpret_cast<char const volatile&>((((T*)0)->*MPtr)));
    }
};

struct PC {
    A t;
};

size_t f() {
    constexpr auto foo = KKP<PC, &PC::t>::c(); // fails to evaluate in the constexpr context
    return 0;
}
```